# Playing mutiple files simultaneously with the PlaySound() API

Tags: c++, winapi, playsound

I've recently discovered how easy it is to play a `wav` file using the Win32 API `PlaySound()` function.

I'm currently implementing it in my game for my background music. I also plan to use it every time my score increases by one. Unfortunately when I do this, and it plays the score sound, then it stops the background music.

Is there a way to have both `wav` files play simultaneously?