# How to play multiple sounds simultaneously using winsound?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

I am trying to layer multiple sounds on top of each other with the built-in winsound library.  I start my 1st sound with

```
winsound.PlaySound("test1.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

When I try to start my other sound

```
winsound.PlaySound("test1.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC 
            | winsound.SND_NOSTOP)
```

I get the not-very-descriptive `RuntimeError: Can't play sound`.
How do I fix that?

Comment: This looks to be based on the Windows PlaySound API function. After googling around a little bit I get the impression that it is not capable of mixing multiple sounds.  The is a SND_NOSTOP flag that you could try but I'm not sure your going to get the exact behavior you desire.  See this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073675/playing-mutiple-files-simultaneously-with-the-playsound-api

Comment: I have the SND_NOSTOP flag, but it's still not working

Comment: I think you need another API.

Comment: Oh well :( .  Any suggestions for something that would work?  I've seen PyGame suggested, but it seems a little overkill for just playing some background music.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to play two sounds by using winsound and playsound:

```
from playsound import playsound
import winsound
#
filename1 = "C:/Users/sound1.wav"
filename2 = "C:/Users/sound2.wav"
soundfile = filename1
winsound.PlaySound(soundfile, winsound.SND_FILENAME|winsound.SND_ASYNC)
playsound(filename2)
```