# Program not playing sound

Tags: python, winsound

I am programmin a text based game in Python and I want to play effects music over the battle music, I have written the following module to play sounds

```
#Music.py:
#V2
import winsound as ws
def playS(a):
    p=("C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Game\\soundLibrary\\"+(a)+".wav")
    ws.PlaySound(p,ws.SND_ASYNC)

def playE(a):
    p=("C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Game\\soundLibrary\\"+(a)+".wav")
    ws.PlaySound(p,ws.SND_NOSTOP)
```

When the function `playE('effect')` is played the following error message is returned

```
File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Game\Music.py", line 10, in playE
    ws.PlaySound(p,ws.SND_NOSTOP)
RuntimeError: Failed to play sound
```

If anyone could say why it would be appreciated.

(note: `playS()` works fine)

Comment: This might be of help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492900/python-using-multiple-flags-for-winsound

Answer (score 0):

Playsound doesn't actually let you play two sounds simultaeneously, hence it is returning an error.